# Fill in blanks in time series data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that generates this data -

```
FirstName   LstName YYYYMM  Count
Angeline    Boyd    201709  2
Angeline    Boyd    201712  7
Angeline    Boyd    201801  7
Angeline    Boyd    201802  9
```

How do I produce this result instead -

```
FirstName   LstName YYYYMM  Count
Angeline    Boyd    201709  2
Angeline    Boyd    201710  0
Angeline    Boyd    201711  0
Angeline    Boyd    201712  7
Angeline    Boyd    201801  7
Angeline    Boyd    201802  9
```

Zeros were added to 201710 and 201711 because this user didn't have any records for those months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `generate_series()`:

```
select n.*, gs.*, coalesce(t.count, 0) as count
from (select distinct FirstName, LstName
      from t
     ) n cross join
     generate_series('2017-09-01'::date, '2018-02-01'::date, interval '1 month'
                    ) gs(mon) left join
     t
     on t.yyyymm = to_char(gs.mon, 'YYYYMM') and
        t.FirstName = n.FirstName and
        t.LstName  = n.LstName;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5b12922cd7a024807f71004ede4d9718) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I fixed a typo and added a db<>fiddle.